# woocommerce, product link by reviews loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created the very simple loop here, the aim is to extract only reviews that have a value equal to or greater than 4 stars. And so far so good. Now from this loop I would also like to get the link to the specific product. Anyone have any idea how to get this information?

```
$reviews = get_comments( array(
    'status'      => 'approve',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'meta_query'  => array( array(
        'key'     => 'rating',
        'value'   => array('4','5'),
    ) ),
) );

foreach( $reviews as $review) {
   
/* stuff */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working on it a little longer, I gave myself the answer, I attach the solution to my problem:

```
<?php

$reviews = get_comments( array(
    'status'      => 'approve',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'meta_query'  => array( array(
        'key'     => 'rating',
        'value'   => array('4','5'),
    ) ),
) );

foreach( $reviews as $review) {
   
$postId = $review->comment_post_ID;
the_permalink($postId);

}

?>
```